# Neo4j spatial Cypher withinDistance query using lat/lon of results from previous query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, distance, neo4j-spatial

I'm trying to use the results from a **withinDistance** query in a second withinDistance.

I have 2 spatial indexes, Houses and POIs (Points of Interest). I'm trying to find houses which match certains parameters and then find POIs around each house.

This is what I have so far, but I don't know how to pass **house.lon** and **house.lat** as argument in the second withinDistance query

```
START house=node:Houses('withinDistance:[48.0,5.3,100.0]')
MATCH house ... // ... find Houses which match certain parameters
WITH house
    START poi=node:POIs('withinDistance:[house.lon,house.lat,50.0]')
    RETURN house.name, count(poi)
```

**Bonus question**: POIs are linked to POI_Type nodes, how can I return the count of POIs by type around each House?

Cheers :)

Comment: I raised it with the team, perhaps there will be the possibility of having string-expressions for start-items

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately start index lookup statements are not expressions but literals. 
So you'll have to do a client roundtrip for now to construct them :(

Which is unfortunate but I doubt it will change.